# "No provider registered " error occure using geocode packages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

```
https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel/blob/master/config/geocoder.php I cant get pass this point. 1. this is my Job


        public $model;

            public function __construct($model)
            {
                $this->model = $model;
            }

            public function handle()
            {
                $result = new Geocoder();
                $result->geocode($this->model->getAddressString());
              // $result = Geocoder::geocode($this->model->getAddressString());

                $this->model->setCoordinates($result->getLatitude(), $result->getLongitude());
            }
        }
         I followed the instructions in the repo readme to install geocoder into my project.
        2. this is my controller
```

On trying to get Langitude and latitude from address , i get the no provider registered error..

```
         protected function create(array $data)
            {                    

                $user =  User::create([
                    'fname' => $data['fname'],
                    'lname' => $data['lname'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
                    'address_latitude' => $data['address_latitude'],
                    'address_longitude' =>$data['address_longitude'],
                    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                    'gender' => $data['gender'],

                    'dob' => $data['dob'],

                    'health' => $data['health'],
                ]); 

               //$this-> dispatch(new GeocodePartnerAddress($user)); 
                 $this->dispatch(new GeocodeAddress($user));

            }
```

On trying to get Langitude and latitude from address , i get the no provider registered error..

```
    I followed the instructions in the repo readme to install geocoder into my project.
```

I get "No provider registered." this error if you done this problem please give me solution where i am wrong.

Comment: Can you share the **exact** error message? Please add it to your question, not to the comment section

Comment: yes sir off course ""No provider registered."" error

Comment: Is there any stacktrace given? Please add all information to the question

Comment: After having read the documentation: what **exactly** have you configured?

Comment: sir my task is to get langitude and latitude from zipcode. and update it on database. i give you 2 link  i reffered....to follow package installation....1.https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel   2.      https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/get-longitudelatitude-from-address similer code on controller

Comment: yes sir all step followed correctly.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but if everything were configured correctly, you would not see such an error. So, can you share your own configuration? Have you made sure everything is loaded properly (like the environment variable containing the API key?)?

Comment: yes sir your right. i followed every step. documentaion, api,configuration. really i dont get what i missed.

Comment: well sir, i am trying to solve my problem. thanks for the reply. good day sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function handle()
    {     
        $users = User::whereNull('lat')->whereNull('lng')->whereNull('city')->whereNull('state')->whereNull('address')->get();
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            $response = Geocode::make()->address($user->zipcode);  
            if ($response){
                $lat     = $response->latitude();
                $lng     = $response->longitude();
                $city    = $response->raw()->address_components[1]->long_name;
                $state   = $response->raw()->address_components[2]->long_name;               
                $address = $response->formattedAddress();
                echo  $response->locationType();
                DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->update(['lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng, 'city' => $city, 'state' => $state, 'address'=> $address]);
            }
        }exit;        
    }
```